# Scope of an instance variable in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a issue with a instance variable in Python, I need that variable is updated according as run program flow and this don't it , the variable `FO` in my function `chiCuadrado` return a void array, but I'm insert data inside `FO` in my function `frecuenciasObtenidas`. This is my code: I don't know what happen. Please help me, thank you so much

```
def __init__(self, parent = None):
    self.numeros = [] #Definimos un array donde se guardaran los aleatorios generados
    self.FO = [] #Definimos el vector de Frecuencias obtenidas

def frecuenciasObtenidas(self):
    contador1 = 0
    contador2 = 0
    contador3 = 0
    for i in self.numeros:
        i = i/10000.0 #Esto es para que caigan en el rango estipulado
        if i >= 0 and i < 0.1:
            contador1 += 1
        if i >= 0.1 and i < 0.2:
            contador2 += 1
        if i >= 0.2 and i < 0.3:
            contador3 += 1
    self.FO.append(contador1)
    self.FO.append(contador2)
    self.FO.append(contador3)
    print "VECTOR DE FRECUENCIAS", self.FO

def chiCuadrado(self):
  print "soy el vector de frecuencias obtenidas", self.FO
```

Comment: What output are you getting and what is the output you are expecting?

Comment: Does your other code ever call `frecuenciasObtenidas()`?

Comment: I want to have in my function chiCuadrado the variable FO with elements inside, because I assume FO already is full